# Bind Combox inside a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have created a `ListView` with a `ComboBox`

```
<ListView x:Name="lstvAttendance" Margin="0,53,0,10">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Emp Code" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=emp_id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Employee Name" Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="90">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbStatus" Width="75" Text="{Binding Path=status}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=status}">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="P"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="A"/>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="135">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker x:Name="dtpDate" Width="120" Text="{Binding attendance_date}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Reg Date" Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=reg_date}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Update" Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=last_update}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Delete" Width="70">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Content="Remove" Width="60" BorderThickness="0" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource DelImg}" Cursor="Hand" Foreground="Blue"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I need to Bind this `ComboBox`(`ComboBox` has either `P` or `A`).For Binding these `ListView` from DataBase I created a class `Attendance`.

```
public class Attendance
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string emp_id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string status { get; set; }   //Either P or A
     public string attendance_date { get; set; }
     public string reg_date { get; set; }
     public string last_update { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
try
{
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBCon.conStr))
     {
          con.Open();
          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(AppConstraints.LIST_VIEW_ATTENDANCE))
          {
               cmd.Connection = con;
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
               {
                   while (dr.Read())
                   {
                       lstvAttendance.Items.Add(new Attendance()
                       {
                             Id = dr["Id"].ToString(),
                             emp_id = dr["emp_id"].ToString(),
                             name = dr["name"].ToString(),
                             attendance_datedr["attendance_date"].ToString(),
                             status = dr["status"].ToString(),
                             reg_date = dr["reg_date"].ToString(),
                             last_update = dr["last_update"].ToString()
                       });
                   }
               }
          }
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

My code works for other fields in `ListView`. But `ComboBox` value not select. I need help to select `ComboBox` value with respect to Database value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**:Create a `List` of `Attendance` instead of adding items to `lstvAttendance` and then set the `lstvAttendance`'s `ItemsSource`  like this:

```
List<Attendance> lst = new List<Attendance>();
try
{
  ....
  ....
  while (dr.Read())
  {
     lst.Add(new Attendance()
     {
        ....
     }
  }
  ...
  ...
  lstvAttendance.ItemsSource = lst;
}
catch
{
  ....
}
```

**Secondly**: You missed the `ItemsSource` property of your `ComboBox` it should be like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbStatus" Width="75" DisplayMemberPath="status" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=ItemsSource}"
  SelectedValuePath="status" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=status}">                                    
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SelectedValuePath` binding then bind to the `SelectedValue=status` property of viewModel.
Binding to `SelectedItem` will always contain the actually selected item ( ComboBoxItem) not the actual value.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbStatus" Width="75" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=Content}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=status}">
       <ComboBoxItem Content="P"/>
       <ComboBoxItem Content="A"/>
 </ComboBox>
```